# Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech Container - API Key

Tags: containers, azure-cognitive-services, speech

For the username and APIKey that connects the container back to azure, is there a way to store that in a local Azure Key Vault? How is this not exposed in code for the docker container?

Comment: What do you mean by local Azure Key Vault? you mean a local container with keyvault? or a way in the speech container to connect to a cloud Key Vault in your subscription and pull the keys?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to retrieve the key vault in the local or the docker, you could implement it with the rest API or the SDK.

Firstly about rest API, you could refer to this tutorial, it uses the python to do the rest request: [Use Azure Key Vault with a Windows virtual machine in Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-python-windows-virtual-machine).

It describes how to assign an identity to the VM and assign permissions to the VM identity

And about the SDK, here is a sample about python SDK to access Key Vault: [Azure Key Vault libraries for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-python).